# Changing server for SQL database

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to change server for my database from my Wamp server, to my ftp server.

When I'm trying to import the database from the zip folder that I Created from the database I exported from my local servers phpmyadmin (wamp), I get the error:

```
#1044 - Access denied for user '111481-px75927'@'%' to database 'shop'
```

Anyone got a clue what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should  create a new user at the old database with the same name of the new user at the new database before you backed up and exported the database.

for example you have in the new hosting site a user "**user1**" you should add the user "**user1**" at the existing database before you exported it and imported it to the new site.

Comment: So you get this error  because the database is already created so you won't be able to execute the statement **CREATE DATABASE**. Instead, replace it with "USE shop;" or the actual name of the database.

Comment: You can read this article :

https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/129/Export+and+import+MySQL+databases#gs/method2-import

and this:
http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/how-to-import-your-mysql-database